# What is causing duplicate class definition for java.lang.ClassLoader$ByteBuddyAccessor$V1 with INJECTION strategy?

Tags: java, byte-buddy

When updating to bytebuddy 1.12.22 (from 1.10.14) we have started occasionally seeing exception indicating that java.lang.ClassLoader$ByteBuddyAccessor$V1 is (already) in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'.
We have bytebuddy (shaded into one of our jars) included in our wars. We only occasionally see this issue when we have multiple wars running in the same tomcat instance. For tomcat instances with only 1 war or simple single classpath applications, there are never issues.

We are calling DynamicType.Unloaded.load with a classloader from class in same war and ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.INJECTION strategy.

https://javadoc.io/static/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.14.4/net/bytebuddy/dynamic/DynamicType.Unloaded.html#load-S-net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassLoadingStrategy-

This is failing with message:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot define class using reflection: java.lang.LinkageError: loader 'bootstrap' attempted duplicate class definition for java.lang.ClassLoader$ByteBuddyAccessor$V1. (java.lang.ClassLoader$ByteBuddyAccessor$V1 is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

It looks like there was a change which moved from generating an accessor class from having a random name to always using "V1".
https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/commit/201c6b69480b5b9ee35b5cdc9e35fb1bab2005dc#diff-f2e06c83c21b2a52e4ebf4392e271c68d13cdc2e5fba055773f1ffd81ce18776

[image: github change]

Is this the expected behavior? Is it not allowed to have byte buddy in multiple wars in the same tomcat instance, or at least not allowed if using INJECTION strategy?

Comment: What version did you update from?

Comment: @RafaelWinterhalter updated from 1.10.14 - updated the question to clarify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The corresponding code looks checks if the class is already loaded:

```
synchronized (classLoader == null
  ? BOOTSTRAP_LOADER_LOCK
  : classLoader) {
    for (Map.Entry<? extends String, byte[]> entry : types.entrySet()) {
      try {
        result.put(entry.getKey(), Class.forName(entry.getKey(), false, classLoader));
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException ignored) {
        result.put(entry.getKey(), dispatcher.defineClass(classLoader, entry.getKey(), entry.getValue(), protectionDomain));
      }
    }
  }
```

This should prevent the error you are experiencing. Could you check why this happens? The change was made to support GraalVM which struggles with randomized names.

I could not reproduce this, at least: https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/commit/fa4b2ac09db71352c248900a633a4adc0d69124b

Comment: But if byte-buddy itself is in 2 different wars, on 2 different classpaths, aren't there 2 different BOOTSTRAP_LOADER_LOCK instances?

Comment: That's true. Thanks for your PR, that will fix that issue.